# More than 10k connections on linux vps

Tags: linux, vps

My question what is causing this and how to check?

we use url masking script is the website..is it causing this?please help

```
We could noticed that you are abusing our network, as you have made more than 10k connections in our node due to this our node became unstable and all of our customer faced down time because of your VPS. Please find the log details below for your reference.

==============================
593 src=199.231.227.56 dst=58.2.236.196
465 src=199.231.227.56 dst=192.223.243.6
396 src=199.231.227.56 dst=58.2.238.191
217 src=199.231.227.56 dst=58.2.236.197
161 src=199.231.227.56 dst=20.139.83.50
145 src=199.231.227.56 dst=192.223.163.6
136 src=199.231.227.56 dst=125.21.230.68
134 src=199.231.227.56 dst=125.21.230.132
131 src=199.231.227.56 dst=20.139.67.50
117 src=199.231.227.56 dst=110.234.29.210
112 src=199.231.227.56 dst=65.52.0.51
104 src=199.231.227.56 dst=202.46.23.55
100 src=199.231.227.56 dst=202.3.120.4
94 src=199.231.227.56 dst=117.198.39.22
69 src=203.197.253.62 dst=199.231.227.56
62 src=14.194.248.225 dst=199.231.227.56
53 src=199.231.227.56 dst=192.223.136.5
52 src=49.248.11.195 dst=199.231.227.56
51 src=199.231.227.56 dst=117.198.38.15
50 src=199.231.227.56 dst=192.71.175.2
47 src=199.231.227.56 dst=61.16.189.76
45 src=199.231.227.56 dst=122.177.222.17
43 src=199.231.227.56 dst=115.242.89.40
42 src=199.231.227.56 dst=103.22.237.215
41 src=125.16.9.2 dst=199.231.227.56
39 src=199.231.227.56 dst=117.198.35.90
38 src=199.231.227.56 dst=203.91.201.54
38 src=199.231.227.56 dst=14.139.241.89
38 src=199.231.227.56 dst=111.93.85.82
37 src=199.231.227.56 dst=65.52.0.56

Note: 1st column indicates the total number of connections to a particular IP.

You have totally made more than 10k connections.
```

Answer (score 2):

That's not much of a log. If they are only sending you that and telling you to take a hike - I would find another VPS host.

We will need more information like:

- What is the primary purpose of the VPS?
- What OS does the VPS use?
- Perhaps your VPS was hacked?
- Have you checked user logs and user accounts?
- What do any of the logs say? Look for abnormal entries.

Comment: Agreed. Also, the message they are sending you sounds pretty unprofessional, and not just because it's in broken English.